# Difference between Start and End row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame and want to subtract two rows, to calculate the timings between a start and an end event. Is there a possibility to speed up this code:

```
   frame = dataframe[dataframe['action'] == action]
   rows = []
   beginRow = None
   for index, row in frame.iterrows():
       if row['action_marker'] == 'Start':
           beginRow = row[['datetime', 'ns']]
       elif row['action_marker'] == 'End':
           diffRow = row[['datetime', 'ns']] - beginRow
           diffRow['datetime'] = row['datetime']
           rows.append(diffRow)
```

for data:

```
datetime    ns    action_marker
16:13:59.559    15600315840824  End 
16:13:59.559    15600315909589  Start
16:13:59.561    15600317346752  End 
16:13:59.561    15600317425992  Start
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using masking: something like ``frame[frame['action_marker'] == 'Start'] - frame[frame['action_marker'] == 'End']``. Note that this will fail if there are unmatched start/end rows.

Comment: thx, but yeah..thats what i want to avoid.. :)

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that? It's the best way to do what you ask.

Comment: because i can not assume, that there are equal start/end tags

Comment: OK – then you should modify the question to be explicit about what you want to do in case the start/end tags don't align. Your current method ignores repeated start tags, and treats repeated end tags as if they have the same start value. Is this your desired behavior?

Comment: i rewrote my logging method, so i log now the duration itself. Thanks anyways!